# How can I connect an angular component to a dialog component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a confirmation dialog for a delete button. I have 1 component for all the operations and another component for the dialog. I want that when the user clicks the "Delete" button, it will execute the method that was implemented on the other component. Here are my codes.

uploadlist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadlistService } from '../service/uploadlist.service';
import { CostSpreadsheet } from '../model/costSpreadsheet.model';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DeleteDialogComponent } from '../shared/delete-dialog/delete-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploadlist',
  templateUrl: './uploadlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploadlist.component.css']
})
export class UploadlistComponent implements OnInit {

  private costSpreadsheet:CostSpreadsheet [];

  constructor(private _uploadlistService:UploadlistService, public dialog: MatDialog) {   }

  //list files from cost spreadsheet table
  ngOnInit() {
    this._uploadlistService.getFiles().subscribe((costSpreadsheet) => {
      console.log(costSpreadsheet);
      this.costSpreadsheet = costSpreadsheet;
      });
    };

  deleteFile(file: CostSpreadsheet) {
    this._uploadlistService.deleteFile(file).subscribe((data) => {
      this.costSpreadsheet = this.costSpreadsheet.filter(f => f!== file);
    }
  )}; 

 openDialog () {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    this.dialog.open(DeleteDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  } 
}
```

uploadlist.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CostSpreadsheet } from '../model/costSpreadsheet.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadlistService {

  private uploadUrl:string = 'http://localhost:8080/bluecost';
  private uploader:string = "X91927";
  private costSpreadsheet = new CostSpreadsheet();

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  getFiles(): Observable<CostSpreadsheet[]> {
    return this._http.get<CostSpreadsheet[]>(this.uploadUrl + "/costspreadsheet/" + this.uploader)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getFiles', [])));
  }

  deleteFile(file: CostSpreadsheet) {
    return this._http.delete(this.uploadUrl + "/spreadsheet/" + file.uploader + "/" + file.fileName, {responseType: 'text'}) 
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('deleteFile', [])));
  }

   private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
          console.error(error); // log to console instead
          return of(result as T);
        };
   }    
}
```

uploadlist.component.html

```
<table class="ds-table ds-table-compact order-column stripe cell-border" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Number of Records</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let f of costSpreadsheet">
    <td>{{ f.fileName }}</td>
    <td>{{ f.noOfRecords }}</td>
    <td>{{ f.totalChargeAmount }}</td>
    <td *ngIf="f.status == 'SUBMITTED'"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="openDialog(f)">Delete</button></td>
    <td *ngIf="f.status == 'COMPLETED'">SUBMITTED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

delete-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, OnInit, Input, Inject,  EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { UploadlistComponent } from '../../uploadlist/uploadlist.component';
import { CostSpreadsheet } from '../../model/costSpreadsheet.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-dialog',
  templateUrl: './delete-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-dialog.component.css']
})
export class DeleteDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  private file: CostSpreadsheet;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteDialogComponent>) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dialogRef.updateSize('40%', '40%');
    this.dialogRef.updatePosition({ left: '350px' });     
  }

  delete() {  

  }      

  cancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }    
}
```

delete-dialog.component.html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete File</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>
  <h5>Are you sure? This will be permanently deleted.</h5>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: What happens with what you have so far? And it might be easier to parse if instead of including *everything*, you just include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really the way to use dialogs. Normally a confirmation dialog just returns a result when closed, and the result is used by the calling component to take appropriate action. It normally does this through a `close()` function parameter or the `button[matDialogClose]` directive, and through the `MatDialogRef.afterClosed()` function. A 'result' for a confirmation dialog is normally yes or no - true or false - confirmed or cancelled. So a simple confirmation dialog's actions would look something like (partial code):

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button class="mat-raised-button" [matDialogClose]="false">Cancel</button>
  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" [matDialogClose]="true">Delete</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

There is no need to write any logic at all in the confirmation dialog component - just send back the user's action result.

In your code, since you have a bunch of things in place already, you could return the yes/no result easily through your `delete()` and `cancel()` functions using `MatDialogRef.close()`:

```
delete() {  
  this.dialogRef.close(true);
}      

cancel() {
  this.dialogRef.close(false);
}
```

In both cases you need to handle the confirmation result in the code where you launch the dialog:

```
this.dialog.open(DeleteDialogComponent).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result) {
    // delete
  } else {
    // no action
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

An EventEmitter or a shared broadcaster service with a behavioralSubject to broadcast the event seems useful in this situation.

For broadcaster service, use a RxJs BehaviorSubject to emit the message. The message can be subscribed in the receiving component. An example can be seen in this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)